# convert NSString to an NSArray with more than one condition

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, nsstring, nsarray

I have a string that contains some text with periods and commas. I'd like to convert it to an NSArray based on the commas AND the periods. I use this method to separate based on one type of condition, but how do I do that with two?

```
componentsSeparatedByString:
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 NSString *tempTextOut = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"jdnfj,adsfsajfhkj,hasdfjhdsjkfh,hdsufhajkdsfhk"];
NSMutableArray *array = [[tempTextOut componentsSeparatedByString: @","] mutableCopy];
NSLog(@"%@",array);
```

**>>OutPut1**

```
jdnfj,
adsfsajfhkj,
hasdfjhdsjkfh,
hdsufhajkdsfhk
```

and

```
NSString *tempTextOut = [NSString      stringWithFormat:@"jdnfj,adsfsajfhkj,,,hasdfjhdsjkfh,,,,hdsufhajkdsfhk"];
NSMutableArray *array = [[tempTextOut componentsSeparatedByString: @",,,"] mutableCopy];
NSLog(@"%@",array);
```

**>>OutPut2**

```
 "jdnfj,adsfsajfhkj",
hasdfjhdsjkfh,
",hdsufhajkdsfhk"
```

Hope,this will help you..

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question? You can still only separate by one criteria.

Answer (score 9):

You can use `componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:`.

For example:

```
NSString *str = @"1,2.3";

NSArray *arr = [str componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:
                [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@",."]];
```

Please refer to [NSString Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html).

Answer (score 5):

You need to create `NSCharacterSet` with a comma and a dot in it, and use this method:

```
- (NSArray *)componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:(NSCharacterSet *)separator
```

Here is an example:

```
NSArray *arr = [str componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:
      [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@",."]];
```